# The system cannot find the file specified while trying to install JAR with sources with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I was using the followig command to build the project

```
mvn compile exec:java clean install
```

and it was working. I wished it to install sources to local repository and wrote

```
mvn compile exec:java source:jar clean install
```

and now it fails with

```
...
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing MYSOURCEPATH\target\my-library-1.12.1.jar with MYSOURCEPATH\target\my-library-1.12.1-shaded.jar
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: MYSOURCEPATH\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: MYSOURCEPATH\dependency-reduced-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ my-library ---
[INFO] Installing MYSOURCEPATH\target\my-library-1.12.1.jar to MYLOCALREPOPATH\MYLIBRARYPATH\1.12.1\my-library-1.12.1.jar
[INFO] Installing MYSOURCEPATH\dependency-reduced-pom.xml to MYLOCALREPOPATH\MYLIBRARYPATH\1.12.1\my-library-1.12.1.pom
[INFO] Installing MYSOURCEPATH\target\my-library-1.12.1-sources.jar to MYLOCALREPOPATH\MYLIBRARYPATH\1.12.1\my-library-1.12.1-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.280 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-26T18:38:23+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/1373M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project my-library: Failed to install artifact my.library.fqn:my-library:jar:sources:1.12.1: MYSOURCEPATH\target\my-library-1.12.1-sources.jar (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

how to fix/overcome?

Comment: First you should use `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn compile ...clean install` cause the later one will repeat several steps based on the life cycle which is not a good idea and wast of time..Furthermore you should configure the maven-sources-plugin in that way to generate the source packages via a usual `mvn clean package`...nothing more..no supplemental call of a goal like `mvn ... source:jar..`. It would be helpful if you could show the pom file ...

Answer (score 0):

Try
mvn clean source:jar compile install exec:java

Or just:
mvn clean source:jar install exec:java

So basically you need to put the "clean" before the "source:jar"
or else installation for sources will fail